# SwiftUI Canvas: Automatic Preview Updating Paused, Can't resume

Tags: swift, canvas, swiftui, preview

I'm working on my app in XCode 13, with a target deployment of iOS 13. I'm trying to implement SwiftUI, but all Canvases refuse to load. If I select Resume, the preview will pause again without ever loading.
There are no error messages, the preview just pauses again.

I found a similar question on here, but none of the solutions have worked for me. My account isn't at the level yet where I could leave a comment on it.

So far I have tried the following:

- Set Enable Previews in build settings to "Yes"
- Checked off "For install builds only" on all possible items in Build Phases
- Wrapped build phases scripts in an if statement to check if Previews are enabled
- Made a clean build, cleared all derived data.
- Deleted local repository copy and reinstalled from GitHub
- Restarted computer
- added #if DEBUG and #endif to preview code
- Made sure Xcode is not in Legacy Build system.

Other Info:

- App does not use CoreData, and the previews do not involve API calls.
- App is rather large, its size might have something to do with it?
- Xcode will not even show preview for basic "Hello World!" default SwiftUI view.

I'm kind of at a loss at this point as to what else to try.

Please let me know if you have any other questions or suggestions.

Comment: Preview is pretty worthless for us on any of our large apps.  Size of the app seems to negatively affect it.

Comment: Yeah. I'm at my wits end trying to make preview work too. It used toon the same app. I think it's been broken in an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new SwiftUI file was the only thing that worked for me. You can delete it again after the preview recompiles.

Take a look at the process `SimRenderServer` in activity monitor, I think it's this run that Xcode has to relaunch.